# Angular Custom Validator Not Marking FormArray as Invalid

Tags: angular

The custom percentage validator below takes a beneficiaries array as a parameter. beneficiary form is built with planPercents with percent as a formConrol. The console log works for any any plan having over 100% distribution. However, I am unable to successfully return invalid and mark the formArray as invalid.

```
beneficiaries: this.fb.array([], PercentValidator.beneficiaryDistValidator),  

    getPlanPercentGroup(): FormGroup {
        return this.fb.group({
          planUnitId: [null, Validators.required],
          percent: [0, Validators.required],
        });
      }


        import {FormArray} from '@angular/forms';

            export class PercentValidator {

              static beneficiaryDistValidator(formArray: FormArray): ValidationResult {
                if (formArray.controls.length) {
                  // if there is at least one beneficiary
                  const planPercentArray = formArray.at(0).get('planPercents') as FormArray;
                  if (planPercentArray && planPercentArray.controls.length) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < planPercentArray.controls.length; i++) {
                      let planPercentCounter = 0;
                      formArray.controls.forEach(beneficiary => {
                        const planPercentArray2 = beneficiary.get('planPercents') as FormArray;
                        planPercentCounter += planPercentArray2.at(i).get('percent').value;
                        if (planPercentCounter > 100) {
                          console.log('Invalid');
                          return {Invalid: true};
                        }
                      });
                    }
                  }
                }
                return null;
              }
            }

            export interface ValidationResult {
              [key: string]: boolean;
            }
```

Comment: That's because you're trying to return from inside a `forEach` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're trying to return from inside a `forEach` callback. You have to define a variable **outside** the callback, and assign it from **inside**. Then you'll be able to `return` it.